# SetLocalTime gives Error 87 with Remote Debugging

Tags: c#, remote-debugging, kernel32

I have the following C# code:

```
 public static void SetDateTime(System.DateTime datetime)
    {
        var systemNew = new SystemTime
            {
                wDay = (ushort)datetime.Day,
                wMonth = (ushort)datetime.Month,
                wYear = (ushort)datetime.Year,
                wHour = (ushort)datetime.Hour,
                wMinute = (ushort)datetime.Minute,
                wSecond = (ushort)datetime.Second,
                wMilliseconds = (ushort)datetime.Millisecond
            };

        // update system clock
        NativeMethods.SetLocalTime(ref systemNew);
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (errorCode != 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SetDateTime error: {0}", errorCode);
        }
    }

internal struct SystemTime
{
    internal ushort wDay;
    internal ushort wDayOfWeek;
    internal ushort wHour;
    internal ushort wMilliseconds;
    internal ushort wMinute;
    internal ushort wMonth;
    internal ushort wSecond;
    internal ushort wYear;
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int SetLocalTime(ref SystemTime lpSystemTime);
}
```

However, this gives me errorcode 87 everytime I call the method, any ideas?

Edit: I checked it on my local machine and it works fine there.
**It doesn't work with Remote Debugging from Visual Studio, even though the remote process runs under the same account as my local account and it's an administrator on that system.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you posted don't contain any *value* of `datetime` which you used to reproduce the error.

For example `DateTime.Year` property can have the value between 1 and 9999 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx)). On the other side the `wYear` field of `SYSTEMTIME` can be between 1601 and 30827.

So I recommend you first of all to verify *old values* of input struct which you use as the input to `SetLocalTime`.

**UPDATED**: It seems to me that I know the origin of the problem now. You defined `SystemTime` with the **wrong order of fields** as:

```
internal struct SystemTime
{
    internal ushort wDay;
    internal ushort wDayOfWeek;
    internal ushort wHour;
    internal ushort wMilliseconds;
    internal ushort wMinute;
    internal ushort wMonth;
    internal ushort wSecond;
    internal ushort wYear;
}
```

but [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is defined as

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

Comment: The DateTime I used is, for all sense and purposes, DateTime.Now, meaning 25th of May 2012

Comment: @Davio: You written something about Remote Debugging in the "Edit" part of your question. In which security context works the code? Which differences exists between your "local machine" and remote computer? Do you sure that the error which you describes come on the remote computer with `DateTime.Now` parameter or it will be called probably with uninitialized data for example?

Comment: I'll accept it. It works with the correct order AND the assigning of DayOfWeek. This has probably changed at some point due to Resharper trying to reorder my code.

Comment: @Davio: I'm glad to hear that the problem is solved. By the way I see that you almost not use your right to vote. You have right to vote up about 30 questions or answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). Voting it the most important way *to help the searching engine* to find helpful questions and answers. So if you want to help other visitors of the same page you should you your right to vote. (the remark is common and it's not related to my answer). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) you can find simple rule to vote up the helpful answers.

Comment: @Davio: One more remark: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724936(v=vs.85).aspx) of `SetLocalTime` says: **The wDayOfWeek member of the SYSTEMTIME structure is ignored.** So the assigning of `DayOfWeek` is not really needed.

Comment: Oh dear, the order of the fields! Didn't even think to check that.